# iOS How to fill NSMutableArray with searchString?

Tags: ios, search, nsmutablearray, uisearchbar

I want to collect all `searchString` from UISearchBar when the user clicked the button "x" to a mutable array, but however it is being added no object to self.historyList....

In the method:

```
            - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchString
        {
            self.ss = searchBar.text;

//this is initialized in viewDidLoad method
            //self.addSSFort = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            [self.addSSFort addObject: self.ss];

            NSLog (@"addSSFort contains %@", self.addSSFort);

            //NSMutableArray *historyList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]retain];
//this one is initialized in viewDidLoad method
            //self.historyList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            if ([self.ss length] == 0)
            {
        // here it is never being added
                [self.historyList addObject:[self.addSSFort objectAtIndex:[self.addSSFort count]-1]];
            }
    }
```

EDIT :

```
self.addSSFort contains:

x
xc
xco
xcod
xcode <- I want to add this to self.historyList
""
t
tr
tre
tree <- I want to add this to self.historyList
""
```

But self.historyList contains:

```
""
""
```

I want it to contain:

```
xcode
tree
```

I use this statement `if ([self.ss length] == 0)`, because it tells me that the user has clicked on "x" to erase searchString and tells me s/he is finished with the current searchString.
I know about ARC, but I am doing this for the users who have iOS 3 > iOS 5.

EDIT 2:

Ah, I have solved this!

Comment: @nikolai please read my edit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should be:

```
[self.historyList addObject:[self.addSSFort objectAtIndex:[self.addSSFort count]-2]];
```

instead of:

```
[self.historyList addObject:[self.addSSFort objectAtIndex:[self.addSSFort count]-1]];
```

Comment: Broken if addSSFort was empty before.

Comment: @nikolai I know. You are irritated that your answer did not help?

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudocode of your example:

```
get text
add text to array
if text is empty string:
    add empty string to history
```

Is this really what you want?

Comment: You and I have the same idea.

Comment: @nikolai no, your interpretation of my code is wrong. It should being added the string before the string that is empty, that is why [...objectAtIndex:[array count] -1]. Please test the mentioned method which is a part of UISearchBarDelegate.

Comment: @wagashi No your interpretation of how array subscripting works in Cocoa is wrong. `[array objectAtIndex:[array count] - 1]` refers to the last object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand what you are trying to do, but you have

```
If ([self.ss length] == 0)
{
        [self.historyList addObject:[self.addSSFort objectAtIndex:[self.addSSFort count]-1]];
}
```

If you have have text in the search bar then the length of self.ss will not be be 0.  Your "If" statement is blocking the line where you add the object to self.historyList.  Have you placed a break point on the line where you add the string object to you historyList to see if you are getting there?

As a side note, you don't need the retain if you are working with ARC.